# stdin, stdout, stderr in paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client1.exec_command('show version')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client1.exec_command('show interfaces ge-0/0/10')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client1.exec_command('show chassis routing-engine')
print stdout.read()
```

The above script gives output only for last command (`'show chassis routing-engine'`). If I am not wrong the above 2 lines output is overwritten by last command. But how to print all 3 command's output using one print line?

Comment: If you are writing new code, you should definitely start thinking about targetting Python 3. Also, when asking about Python, please make sure you mention that you are still using Python 2.

Comment: In most (not sure if it's ALL) languages the assignment `var = value` would overwrite `var`'s old value.

Comment: @EmilyE. Pascal checks for eqality with `=` like python's `==` so you can ssay the old value would be kept.

Comment: @gonczor Then that cannot be called *assignment*.

Comment: Yes, yes, you're right. I was thinking about changing value by using `=` operator.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to store the output somewhere. Like:

```
stdout_outputs = []

stdin, stdout, stderr = client1.exec_command('show version')
stdout_outputs.append(stdout.read())
stdin, stdout, stderr = client1.exec_command('show interfaces ge-0/0/10')
stdout_outputs.append(stdout.read())
stdin, stdout, stderr = client1.exec_command('show chassis routing-engine')
stdout_outputs.append(stdout.read())

print '; '.join(stdout_outputs)
```